# Regex forward slash separator

Tags: regex

I am using the below regex expression to ensure string is max 50 characters in length and that each word starts with uppercase letter:

```
reMatch("Jet Black","^(?=.{0,50}$)(^|^([A-Z][a-z]* +)*([A-Z][a-z]* *)$)")
```

This works, but I would also like to allow for option to separate words with / character. Example: `Jet/Black` and `Jet / Black` with a space in between.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated! Mike.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care if there may be several spaces, or slahes or intermingled spaces and slashes you may use

```
^(?=.{0,50}$)(?:[A-Z][a-z]*(?:[ /]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ktuzZ9/3).

To only allow spaces and an optional single slash with (white)spaces after use

```
^(?=.{0,50}$)(?:[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s*(?:/\s*)?[A-Z][a-z]*)*)?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ktuzZ9/4)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{0,50}$)` - string should contain only 0 to 50 chars other than linebreak chars (same as `(?!.{51})`)
- `(?:[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s*(?:/\s*)?[A-Z][a-z]*)*)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase ASCII letter and 0+ lowercase ASCII letters
  - `(?:\s*(?:/\s*)?[A-Z][a-z]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of

    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `(?:/\s*)?` - an optional `/` and 0+ whitespaces
    - `[A-Z][a-z]*` -  an uppercase ASCII letter and 0+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.